# Tentando fazer um for em um objeto vue-js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estou tentando fazer um loop (for) em um objeto array no Vue-Js, (javascript) cujo tamanho é 11 (lenght=11) como abaixo. Porém quando faço:

console.log(this.agrupados) // Aqui ele mostra o objeto com length=11

```
  for (var i=0;i<10; i++){
     console.log(i+" Nome:"+this.agrupados.product_name )
  }
```

o loop não funciona. É como se lenght fosse nulo e não 11.

Na inspeção do chrome apresenta isso:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código que tenho é:

```
created() { 
    this.getProducts() // Atualiza valores a receber 
    console.log(this.agrupados) 
    for (var i=0;i<10; i++){ 
        console.log(i+" Nome:"+this.agrupados.product_name ) 
    } 
},
```

Comment: Podes mostrar o código em que isso está inserido? Ou seja, mostra mais código à volta do teu problema.

Comment: Flávio, na verdade ele encontra os dados e por isso faz o for. O problema é que como se trata de um array você precisa passar a posição do array que contenha o atributo. 
Passe no console.log(this.agrupados[i].product_name que deve solucionar o seu problema.

Comment: Tentou `this.agrupados[i].product_name` ?

Comment: created() {
      this.getProducts()
     // Atualiza valores a receber
      console.log(this.agrupados)
      for (var i=0;i<10; i++){
         console.log(i+" Nome:"+this.agrupados.product_name )
      }
  },

Comment: Flavio, o que faz o `this.getProducts()` e o que dá `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.agrupados))`?

Comment: Busca os dados gravados no firestore. console.log e agrupa os dados, totalizando, como está mostrado na figura acima, na inspeção do chrome

Comment: use o código que o @NoobSaibot, creio que ira funcionar

Comment: Flavio, para te podermos ajudar rápido, sem termos de adivinhar, o que dá `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.agrupados))`?

Comment: dá o seguinte: [ ]

Comment: um par de colchetes

Comment: Console.log (this.agrupados) resulta os dados abaixo:

Comment: Agrupados:[]
Lista.vue?16cf:120 0 Nome:undefined
Lista.vue?16cf:120 1 Nome:undefined
Lista.vue?16cf:120 2 Nome:undefined
Lista.vue?16cf:120 3 Nome:undefined
Lista.vue?16cf:120 4 Nome:undefined
Lista.vue?16cf:120 5 Nome:undefined
Lista.vue?16cf:120 6 Nome:undefined
Lista.vue?16cf:120 7 Nome:undefined
Lista.vue?16cf:120 8 Nome:undefined
Lista.vue?16cf:120 9 Nome:undefined

Comment: O Resultado acima, quando faço o codigo abaixo:

Comment: console.log("Agrupados:"+JSON.stringify(this.agrupados))
      for (var i=0;i<10; i++){
         console.log(i+" Nome:"+this.agrupados[i].product_name )
      }

Comment: O estranho é porque quando renderizo no html, ele funciona. Mostra os dados direitinho. Agora quando tento fazer um loop no script, dá: undefined

Comment: @FlavioCardoso se dá `[]` isso é muito importante para o problema. Tens uma logica assíncrona aí e vais precisar de usar `computed` provavelmente. O que faz o `this.getProducts()`?

Comment: Pega os dados no firestore e agrupa, totalizado e gerando o array agrupados

Comment: Fiz o calculo em computed e deu a mesma mensagem

Comment: Sugiro colocares o componente todo para podermos perceber a lógica que tens

Comment: Infelizmente não obtive a solução para meu problema, ainda.Agradeço se alguém puder me ajudar

Comment: Resolvido com a sugestão do @NoobSaibot. Grato. Realmente precisava colocar o índice.: this.agrupados[i].product_name. Muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer um loop em um array em JavaScript existem basicamente três formas:

**1**. Javascript **clássico** (que utiliza o for com um contador):

```
const arrayExemplo = ['A', 'B', 'D'];

for (let i = 0; i < arrayExemplo.length; i++) {
    console.log(`${i} ${arrayExemplo[i]}`);
}
```

**2**.  Javascritp **moderno** (utiliza a estrutura [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)):

```
const arrayExemplo = ['A', 'B', 'D'];

for (const value of arrayExemplo) {
    console.log(`${value}`)
}
```

**3**. Utilizando o método [**forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) (que faz parte do objeto [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)).

```
const arrayExemplo = ['A', 'B', 'D'];

arrayExemplo.forEach(function(item, index) {
    console.log(`${index} ${item}`);
})
```

Answer (score -3):

`const user = {};
 user.name = "Eduardo";
 user.idade = 21;`

```
for(let item in user){

 // item =>  Nome da propriedade
 // user[item] => Valor da propriedade

 console.log( item + ' => ' + user[item] )

}
```